# Does perl DBI support command like this @file_name?

Tags: perl, dbi

I would like to run commands which is placed in 1.sql file  This is my code:

```
$sth=$dbh->do( q { @1.sql } );
```

But this code isn't working:

There is output:

```
DBI::db=HASH(0xf18edc0) trace level set to 0x0/2 (DBI @ 0x0/0) in DBI 1.634-ithread (pid 10389)
    -> do in DBD::_::db for DBD::Oracle::db (DBI::db=HASH(0xf18ee50)~0xf18edc0 ' @1.sql ') thr#eebf010
   dbd_st_execute (STMT TYPE 0) (out0, lob0)...
Statement Execute Mode is 32 (COMMIT_ON_SUCCESS)
    -> DESTROY for DBD::Oracle::st (DBI::st=HASH(0xf18f190)~INNER) thr#eebf010
       ERROR: 900 'ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement (DBD ERROR: error possibly near <*> indicator at char 1 in ' <*>@1.sql ')' (err#1)
    <- DESTROY= undef at run.pl line 12
    !! ERROR: 900 'ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement (DBD ERROR: error possibly near <*> indicator at char 1 in ' <*>@1.sql ')' (err#0)
    <- do= undef at run.pl line 12
DBD::Oracle::db do failed: ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement (DBD ERROR: error possibly near <*> indicator at char 1 in ' <*>@1.sql ') [for Statement " @1.sql "] at run.pl line 12.
DBD::Oracle::db do failed: ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement (DBD ERROR: error possibly near <*> indicator at char 1 in ' <*>@1.sql ') [for Statement " @1.sql "] at run.pl line 12.
!   -> DESTROY for DBD::Oracle::db (DBI::db=HASH(0xf18edc0)~INNER) thr#eebf010
       ERROR: 900 'ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement (DBD ERROR: error possibly near <*> indicator at char 1 in ' <*>@1.sql ')' (err#0)
!   <- DESTROY= undef during global destruction
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that won't work (obviously). Some DBI drivers support multiple statements (MySQL and SQL Server via ODBC come to mind), but I don't think Oracle does. At any rate, you'd still have to handle the file reading part yourself. As you can see in the [DBI docs](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#do), `do()` is expecting a valid SQL statement, which the string `@1.sql` is not.

Answer (score 1):

Your basic options for executing an SQL file from Perl are:

**Split the SQL file yourself and then execute each statement.**

If you have control of the file and know it won't contain anything tricky, this is a fairly easy task.  It could be as easy as splitting the file based on a semicolon character, or you might want to add some basic stripping of comments first.

However, this is quite hard to do 100% correctly for the full range of possible file content (what if an SQL statement has a string containing a semicolon?  What if there are nested sets of comments?  etc.).  This requires fully parsing the file--and I'm not aware of any tool that allows you to do this easily.  There is an `SQL::Parse` module, but I don't think it handles multiple statements.

**Call an external program from Perl to do it for you.**

For example, call the Oracle command line client.  This is easy, but you don't have granular control of the statements being executed.